# Exporting non-dataframe data to a text file in R

Tags: r, dataframe, phylogeny

This is the code I am using, this creates a summary of stastistical tests I am interested in

```
library(ape)
library(geiger)
library(caper)

taxatree <- read.tree("newicktest.tre")
LWEVIYRcombodata <- read.csv("LWEVIYR.csv")


LWEVIYRcombodataPGLS <-data.frame(Sum.of.percentage=LWEVIYRcombodata$Sum.of.percentage,OGT=LWEVIYRcombodata$OGT, Species=LWEVIYRcombodata$Species)

LWEVIYRcombodataPGLS$Species<-gsub(" ", "", LWEVIYRcombodataPGLS$Species)

comp.dat <- comparative.data(taxatree, LWEVIYRcombodataPGLS, "Species")

phylo.signal <- pgls((Sum.of.percentage) ~1, data=comp.dat, lambda="ML")
```

I call this up with the line:

```
summary(phylo.signal)
```

And then save it as a variable:

```
dataforexport <- summary(phylo.signal)
```

However, this won't let me print it to a regular text file, or even a csv.

When trying something along the lines of this:

```
write.table(dataforexport, file = "test1.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)
```

I get an error message:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""summary.pgls"" to a data.frame
```

I want to be able to save the results of my analysis to a text file, or even a csv (ideally appending the file, but that's another question that's probably been answered somewhere else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try -

`capture.output(summary(phylo.signal), file = "test1.txt")`

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Is there a simple way to get it to append the text file? No worries if the scope of that question is more suitable for another question though!

Comment: I'm going to need to turn this into a loop to turn on thousands of files, ideally I want all the results in one text file, so if there is a way to add to the end of the .txt file rather than just writing a new file each time, that'd be awesome!

Comment: Oh I see. Mm, that might be a bit tough. You could save the outputs to different elements of a list and then use `capture output` which would just give a single .txt file with lots of rows, but I think there is a 10,000 row limit on exporting in this way, so it depends how large the files are... Sorry, maybe it would be better to ask another question and see what other folk can suggest.

Comment: Yeah it's a million files and roughly 10gb worth of data, so my plan is to close the loop and rm(list=ls()) at the end, all I want to be doing is adding a bit of text to a text file, anything else would be too much for the RAM I imagine, and R...

Comment: Depends on how you build the loop, anything you read in within a loop only exists in that loop. So at the end of each iteration any input file will be overwritten. You shouldn't need to `rm(list=ls())`

Comment: You might be better off going down the route of working out what each of the functions return (often lists of lists). I've had to do that, extracting the important pieces of information and storing them in a custom dataframe which you can then save at the end of the loop. Although you are working with a lot of files, if you only need a couple of pieces of information from each function output, it might not get too large.